# Iterate UIProgressView animation Programmatically - Swift

Tags: swift, animation, textview, uiprogressview

I have set up a progressView and a textView, I want the progressView to animate its progress bar and when completed, to reset it, simultaneously changing the textView and start the animation again.

This is what I tried:

```
var iterator : Int = 0


fileprivate func setUpAnimation(){
    
    switch iterator {
    case 0:

        interactiveShowTextView.text = quotesArray[iterator]
        animateAndIterate()

    case 1:

        interactiveShowTextView.text = quotesArray[iterator]
        animateAndIterate()

    case 2:


        interactiveShowTextView.text = quotesArray[iterator]
        animateAndIterate()

    default:

            self.iterator = 0
            self.setUpAnimation()

}
```

}

```
fileprivate func animateAndIterate(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
        self.progressBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.progressBar.progress = 1.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.progressBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { finished in
            print("animation completed")
            self.iterator += 1
            self.setUpAnimation()

        })
    })
}
```

It works fine only at the beginning when the iterator is 0, but when I iterate it to 1 the textView starts going mad continuously changing textView texts.
I don't actually know why

Comment: what is progress bar lenght ? 0-1 or 0-10

Comment: It is 0-1 @jawadAli

Comment: what is setupAnimation

Comment: @jawadAli it's the same function that contains the switch.
 I'm calling it again whenever the animation finishes, I'm basically calling the same function changing the iterator so that switch can detect the value of the iterator and act accordingly

Comment: strange .. i think you are going to wrong side ...

Comment: What do you mean?